# Can we based on Android Studio Emulators for different display screens create the App

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Can we based on Android Studio Emulators for different display screens create the App? Can we trust Android Studio Emulators ?

I mean for example whatever that's displayed on the Nexus 7 Emulator, would be exactly the same as it is really displayed on the real Tablet itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can.
I've compared lots of emulators vs real devices - they are almost identical

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulators give you a basic idea of different layout. Padding and pixel adjustment may be different in real device due to difference between system screen resolution and real device screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Emulator is built [hand-in-hand](https://youtu.be/Hx_rwS1NTiI?t=35s) with the Android platform for the Android SDK. Moreover, the latest Android Emulator system images (API 24+) 100% pass the [Android Compatibility Definition](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd), so that you can have even more assurance that app behavior will be exactly the same between the Android Emulator and a physical Android device.